# Uri with file:// scheme won't load into Glide

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I have tried many ways already, but here is my URI:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Images/IMG-20171101-WA0003.jpg
```

I have tried using:

```
.load(urinormal)
```

at first. It works as long the URI has a content:// scheme, but not for file://

Other things I tried:

```
.load(new File(urinormal.getPath()))
.load(Uri.fromFile(new File(urinormal.getPath())))
```

Read and write storage permission are both granted, in manifest and on runtime.

Edit: My Uri comes from:

```
    ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image);
    Glide.with(this).load(getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)).into(image);
```

Comment: please look into this issue : [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/867)

Comment: I have looked into it and it appers to be a different issue.

Comment: Have you tried replacing %20 to a space and then load it?

Comment: @KanakSony I just tried it out and it also did not work.

Comment: `getIntent().getParcelableExtra` You have not shown  us what you put in that intent. And from where. And what type would be delivered by that call?